# MSDeploy to multiple servers

Tags: asp.net, web-services, configuration, msdeploy

I am looking for a way to deploy to multiple different environments.

ie, dev, uat, prod1, and prod2 servers

I am under the impression msdeploy could work for this. Currently we have something that deploys using a command like

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:contentPath="D:\sourcepath" -dest:contentPath="D:\destpath", computerName=PRODSERVER1


"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:contentPath="D:\sourcepath" -dest:contentPath="D:\destpath", computerName=PRODSERVER2
```

This would work, but in the application I'm developing that needs deploying has a database connection involved, which needs to be changed per environment.

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="DEVServer" connectionString="Data Source=DEVServer\SQLinstance;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=sqluser;Password=sqlpassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Also, since this is a WCF service I have an Identity for the endpoint that would need to be changed  per environment as well

```
<identity>
            <dns value="DEVServer" />
</identity>
```

Is there a way to parameterize this? Should I set up multiple web.config files? What is the easiest route to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, you can set up a publish profile for each environment and put the database connection string in that, set up a Web.config transform for each publish profile to make the endpoint changes, and you can deploy using MSBuild from the command line instead of msdeploy directly.

For details on how to set up publish profiles, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx

For Web.config transform examples, see http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-web-config-file-transformations-3-of-12

On publishing from the command line, the format would be like the following for publishing a solution:

msbuild path\to\solution.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=[nameofprofile] /p:Password=[password]

To publish a project rather than a solution, specify the .csproj/.vbproj file and add /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 for VS 2012 (10.0 for VS 2010).

Comment: This does not work. If servers have different credentials and you tell msbuild to deploy a single solution, then it will try to use the same username and password for both servers. Thus resulting in an unauthorized error. Can/Should we deploy .csproj files instead?